# Set Popup Window Specific Position?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

Actually in my Application Login Page is Popup..

```
private var login:Login;

        protected function loginPopUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            login = new Login();
            PopUpManager.addPopUp(login,this,true);
            PopUpManager.centerPopUp(login);
        }
```

Hear Popup coming Center ....
But I want Popup Below the Button..

i.e... When we click the login Button Popup will open Below the Button..

Comment: Can you just the x and y values on the popup to place it below the button?

Comment: set button depth more then and popup depth..

Comment: give me small example for more understand..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it depends what `this` is. If `this` for example is your Login button you can easily do like this:

```
protected function loginPopUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                login = new Login();
                PopUpManager.addPopUp(login,this,true);
                PopUpManager.centerPopUp(login);
                login.x += loginButton.width / 2; // or any other number
                login.y += 123; //whatever number. try tweaking it
            }
```

If your want to use display object as `FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as DisplayObject` then you probably want to get you login button from `event.target` and manipulate with its coordinates. Just try to experiment.
Also you maybe will have to use `localToGlobal` property when playing with coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var sym:Login = PopUpManager.createPopUp( this, Login) as Login;
    sym.x     = button.x; 
    sym.y     = button.y+button.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Working for me:

```
protected function loginPopUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                login = new Login();
                login.x = 10; // x value relative to "this"
                login.y = 123; // y value relative to "this"
                PopUpManager.addPopUp(login,this,true);

             }
```